# Looping one webpage

Tags: java, jquery, loops, html

I'm not that great with html so I need your help!

I would like to make 1 single webpage loop.

So what I mean is:

1. I click the button or image
2. it goes to the next page that says you are connected)
3. Automatically goes back to the first button page to be clicked again.

It sounds easy, but to me it's not.

Would greatly appreciate the help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how long you want the second page to be displayed, you could either have a button to return to the original page or a timer to do it. **So in PAGE 2 you can choose one of the options below:**

**WITH A BUTTON (User chooses to go back)**

```
 <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

 <script>
 function goBack() {
     window.history.back();
 }
 </script>
```

**WITH A TIMER (5 seconds and pages goes back automatically)**

```
 <script>
 setInterval(goBack, 5000); // a delegate to goBack function to be called after 5000 miliseconds

 function goBack() {
     window.history.back();
 }
 </script>
```

Check the references:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: THanks very much for your reply! Both make sense now

Answer (score 0):

Make two pages first page lets call **page1.html** and second page we will call **page2.html**.

**page1.html** will include a `<a>` tag around an image.

`<a href="http://www.someDomain.com/page2.html"><img scr="someimg.png"/></a>`

This will send you to **page2.html**.

Now in **page2.html** have

```
<p>you are connected</p>
```

With the following Jquery, this will wait 5 seconds then redirect you back to **page1.html**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "https://www.someDomain.com/page1.html";
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```